# Jquery positioning?

Tags: jquery, css, position

I have a dynamic height div that gets inserted into the dom when you ctrl click on an html input.

What I want to do is have the bottom right hand corner match up with the top right hand corner of the input that was clicked.

What css styles/jQuery must I use to position this correctly?

I cannot include jQuery UI so please do not suggest it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by match up?

Comment: as in the bottom right corner of my div must touch the top right corner of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) which return top left coordinates relative to document. Then you can add elemtent's width ( [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) ), to get top right corner.

And to position the div there, use the same technique on div, only remove height ( [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) ) and width.

Just a small note, that you must account for borders, margins and paddings, as jQuery doesn't include those in width / height.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery plugin [PositionCalculator](https://github.com/tlindig/position-calculator).

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var count = 1;
  var $popup = $('#popup');

  function showPopup(event) {

    // reset position
    $popup.show().css({top:0, left:0});

    // calculate new position
    var calculator = new $.PositionCalculator({
      item: $popup,
      itemAt: "bottom left",
      target: this,
      targetAt: "top right",
      flip: "both"
    });
    var posResult = calculator.calculate();

    // set new position
    $popup.css({
      top: posResult.moveBy.y + "px",
      left: posResult.moveBy.x + "px"
    });
  }

  // initial add event handler
  $('.has_popup').on('click', showPopup);
  $popup.on('click', function() { $popup.hide(); });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="has_popup"  value="click me"/>

<div id="popup" style="display:none; position:absolute; padding:10px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); color:#ffffff">
  I am the popup. <b>Click me to close</b>
</div>
```

Here is the [example at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fetoy/2/edit?html,js,output)